# XPath to find elements with attributes

Tags: xpath

How can I find elements that has at least one attribute?

Example:

```
<tr>...</tr>
<tr style="">...</tr>
<tr width="">...</tr>
```

I want all tr elements but ...

I tried following xpath but it doesn't work.

```
//table//tr[contains(attributes::*,'')]
```

Thanks

Comment: XPather might help: http://xpath.alephzarro.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
//table/tr[@*]
```

The reason why yours doesn't work is because `contains()` will always return true when the second parameter is `''`. When an expression returns a node set within square brackets, it is considered true if it's non-empty, false if it's empty. So `[@*]` will return the set of all attributes and will be interpreted as true if there are any present.

Comment: No, it returns all rows. I believe all strings will contain ''. That's why it is returning all tr nodes.

Comment: @priyank: I just gave it a test in Visual Studio's XSLT interpreter and my example works as expected.

Comment: @priyank: It surely isn't the same. Use XPather and inspect this page, using `//div` and `//div[@*]` - they yield different number of items.

Comment: Your example works perfect. I was talking about the XPath I wrote earlier. /tr[contains(attributes::*,'')]

Thx.